# Did Bob Corker ask Trump for his endorsement?

Tags: united-states, politics, donald-trump

President Trump just tweeted this (see [here](https://twitter.com/realdonaldtrump/status/1076929590050897920?s=21) and [here](https://twitter.com/realdonaldtrump/status/1076935567760338944?s=21)):

> Senator Bob Corker just stated that, “I’m so priveledged to serve in the Senate for twelve years, and that’s what I told the people of our state that’s what I’d do, serve for two terms.” But that is Not True - wanted to run but poll numbers TANKED when I wouldn’t endorse him.... Bob Corker was responsible for giving us the horrible Iran Nuclear Deal, which I ended, yet he badmouths me for wanting to bring our young people safely back home. **Bob wanted to run and asked for my endorsement.** I said NO and the game was over. #MAGA I LOVE TENNESSEE!

Senator Corker responded to this by [saying](https://twitter.com/senbobcorker/status/1076935303158476800?s=21) "Yes, just like Mexico is paying for the wall... #AlertTheDaycareStaff", which presumably means he denies President Trump's allegations.

My question is, is President Trump right that Senator Corker asked him for his endorsement?

Comment: Trump isn't a reliable source of information.

Comment: @JoeW saying that Trump isn’t a reliable source of information is like saying someone in a hospital isn’t in good health.

Comment: Good question, but I don’t think we’d ever know for sure unless Sen. Corker acknowledges it himself (which is probably unlikely).